# Rails Tutorial 3 chapter 7.1.3 rspec failing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I have spend a few hours going over the book and the code from the github page, and I cannot seem to find my answer. I am in chapter 7.1.3 and trying to get the following tests to pass. When I view the pages everything is working properly as far as I can tell.

**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',     text: 'Sign Up') }               (10)
    it { should have_selector('title',  text: full_title('Sign Up')) }   (11)
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',     text: 'user.name') }              (18)
    it { should have_selector('title',  text: 'user.name') }              (19)
  end
end
```

I have been through all of the files that I can think of checking what could go wrong.

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

**app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

**app/controller/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'

  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'

  root :to => 'pages#home'
```

I think I have attached all of the relevant code, please let me know if adding anything else will help. The following are the actual errors that I am getting. If you can please point out where I have thrown a wrench in the works I would be very appreciative.

```
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:10 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages profile page
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks in line 18 and 19. That should pass your tests.

Like this:

```
describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title',   text: user.name) }
  end
```

Also look for your routes.rb. In the rails tutorial it is well

```
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

unless you have create the static pages views with the name pages. Then forget my routes.rb

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that did not work. Anything else I could be overlooking?